# How to set up Bootstrap slideshow properly

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

So I am making a slideshow for hair page and wanted to use the bootstrap Carousel class. However when I use it my pictures stack on top of each other instead appearing once you click the controls. How would I go about solving this

```
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-centered">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="chocolate.jpg" alt="Los Angeles">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="clip1.PNG" alt="Chicago">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="clip2.PNG" alt="New York">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Slideshow:

[image]

```
.col-centered {
float: none;
margin: 0 auto;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must change the class of the image to "carousel-item", not just "item". Just like the example below

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  
  <div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-centered">
  <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="Los Angeles">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="Chicago">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/any" alt="New York">
      </div>
    </div>

   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check if you have linked the bootstrap.js file or not!